# From C++Builder to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, c++builder

I'm inheriting a native C++ application.  It was developed with C++Builder.

Right now, I already have a copy of Visual Studio 2008 installed on my system.  Is there anything that would prevent me from building the system with Visual Studio, even though it was developed in C++Builder?

I'm already familiar with Visual Studio, so that's one advantage.  Additionally, it looks like I'd end up with another license fee, to buy C++ Builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the application only uses the Win32 API directly, getting it to work with VC++ is probably a reasonable possibility. If, as seems much more likely, it uses VCL (or one of Borland's other class libraries), then building it with VC++ will probably require a *substantial* (quite possibly bordering on total) rewrite.